# hibernate logging

Tags: hibernate, logging, slf4j

I have an interface that I want Hibernate to log everything to.
My curernt configuration is done programmatically, so I don't have any hibernate.properties or hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
configuration = new Configuration()  
.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver" )
.setProperty( "hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect")
.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://****:5483/postgres")
.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.username", "****")
.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.password", "****")
.setProperty( "hibernate.c3p0.min_size"," 5")
.setProperty( "hibernate.c3p0.max_size"," 20")
.setProperty( "hibernate.c3p0.timeout"," 1800")
.setProperty( "hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"," 50")
.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1" )
.setProperty( "hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread")
.setProperty( "hibernatecache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider")
.setProperty( "hibernate.show_sql", "true" )
.addAnnotatedClass( ... )
.addAnnotatedClass( ... )
;
```

I have a logging interface which has a method

```
public void logLine( String line );
```

How can I

1) specify what is logged

2) redirect the logs to the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is logging output to the stdout. You'll have to somehow intercept it and redirect to your logging mechanism.

Comment: that's not an applicable solution - I know that slf4j has output to file, but it's not what I want either.

Comment: @iliaden: I don't believe Hibernate is logging SQL through slf4j. All versions of Hibernate I used were logging it straight to the stdout.

Comment: @Olaf: "Hibernate utilizes Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) in order to log various system events."   -   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging

Comment: if you know how slf4j works - this would also be a valid solution - I have no experience with slf4j, and I don't know how to redirect it to an interface. google only tells me how to log to file.

Comment: @iliaden: It looks like if you don't set show_sql to true and enable DEBUG logging for org.hibernate.SQL, you will get your SQL into your log file instead of the stdout. Hope it works for you. Otherwise, you can configure slf4j to use your logging framework.

Comment: @olaf: Thanks - but not really. I need to redirect logging to an interface.

Comment: @iliaden: Looks like you will have to implement org.slf4j.Logger interface. You can check out logback project as a sample native implementation of that interface. Good luck!